# nginx wordpress serving index.php instead of functions.js

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have formerly Apache install of wordpress at `/home/wordpress/public_html` and I'd like to use nginx to server it with fastcgi-php at http://*mydomain.com*/admin (this is a bit confusing, this is the main blog url not the wp-admin).

Here the relevant section of my nginx config:

```
location /admin/ {
    root /home/wordpress/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;

    location ~ \/admin\/(.*)\.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$1.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index $document_root/index.php;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* \/admin\/\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

So - this works, kinda. functions.js is coming across as as the same content as index.php - also anything that should be a 404 is coming across as the index page. So http://*mydomain.com*/admin/thisismeaningless is the index page.

Comment: change the order of your location rules, first the one for static files like js and jpg, then the php rule

Comment: @metadings Same result when I ordered them as you mentioned.

Comment: Why are these nested?

Comment: @Melvyn I was just going off of some nginx examples I found. I suppose it could be done otherwise but I'm doing several reverse proxies in the same config file so it seems like it would be more efficient to be nested.

Comment: I was able to cobble together something that is working, although it is non ideal. I've setup a symbolic link at /admin pointing to /public_html in the same folder as /public_html. Then I did a straight forward location directive. It's a bit of a hack, but I'm still not understanding why it doesn't work as written above.

Comment: I am gonna guess you anonimized this config before posting. Either that or the toplevel location block should really be `/wordpress/`.